# How can i migrate my eclipse rcp 3.x ui plugin to e4 rcp?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

Previously i was using eclipse rcp 3.x for the development .Recently I am thinking it to move to e4 rcp.I have many ui plugins which is written in legacy eclipse 3.x.I went through below mentioned tutorial but does not have any clue from where to start.
http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/06/10/how-to-apply-the-e4-programming-model-to-3-x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you reference is for using some of the e4 code (mainly direct injection) in an existing 3.x code base.

If you want to switch to 'pure' e4 then you can't use anything from `.org.eclipse.ui.xxxx` plugins (you can use JFace and SWT code), workspace code (such as `IFile`) is also not available. I converted a personal project to pure e4 but it was a lot of work.

[This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) covers e4 development (there is also a book based on the tutorial). I would suggest going through that to see how e4 works before trying to convert your existing code.

Looking at views, in 3.x you define a view in the plugin.xml and create a class implementing ViewPart. In an e4 application you define the view part in the application model (Application.e4xmi) and the implementing class is a POJO (does not extend anything). The way view menu items are created also changes to use the application model.

Comment: Suppose i have plugin which will contribute view in ui.Than I have a  e4 application .So can I use my plugin which will contribute  a view in e4 application.If yes can you put some light on that.

Comment: Added a bit about views

Comment: So no alternatives to add some kind of compatibility layer or some work around to reuse it..

Comment: You can reuse the SWT and JFace code but the class containing it would need reworking. It really is best to try the tutorial to get an idea of how things work.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help .I will  read that tutorial instead scratching my head  .I am accepting your answer.